# AngularJS: View is updated properly but not the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when implementing a nested list in Angular: the view gets updated properly but, on the other side, the code is not updated on change.

I think it will be much clearer with the code:

```
  _this.categories = injections.map(function (category) {
    return {
      title: category.get('title'),
      object: category,
      criteria: category._criteria.map(function (oneCriteria) {
        return {
          object: oneCriteria,
          type: oneCriteria.get("type"),
          min: _this.range(oneCriteria.get("range")).min,
          max: _this.range(oneCriteria.get("range")).max,
          key: oneCriteria.get("key"),
          value: _this.range(oneCriteria.get("range")).min,
          defaultValue: _this.range(oneCriteria.get("range")).min,
          selected: false
        }
      })
    }
  });

  _this.category = _this.categories[0];

  _this.job = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    salaryAmount: 0,
    salaryTimeUnit: _this.salaryTimeUnits[0],
    category: _this.category.object,
    criteria: _this.category.criteria,
    location: {latitude: 48.137004, longitude: 11.575928}
  };
```

So and, very quick here is my HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="category in controller.categories">
      <input type="radio" name="group" ng-value="category.object.get('title')" id="{{category.object.get('title')}}"
             ng-checked="controller.category == category" ng-click="controller.category = category">
      {{category.title}}
    </div>
    <br>
    Criteria:
    <div ng-repeat="criterium in controller.category.criteria">
      <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
      <span ng-click="criterium.selected = !criterium.selected"
            ng-class="['list-group-item', {active:criterium.selected == true}]">{{criterium.key}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is the following: the value are getting updated in the view (when you click on a radio button on the category, you see the corresponding criteria(s)). But the job is for one reason that I ignore not updated although it has the same reference as the HTML (a reference to this `category.criteria`).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller.job.criteria` is still just a reference to `controller.categories[0]`. Your code should successfully update `controller.category` to point at whichever category you clicked on, but that does not also update the reference in your job data structure.

What you want to do is make your `ngClick` event a bit more robust, i.e.:

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="controller.updateCategory(category)" />
```

and then in your js:

```
_this.updateCategory = function (category) {
  _this.category = category;
  _this.updateJob(category);
};

_this.updateJob = function (category) {
  _this.job.category = category.object;
  _this.job.criteria = category.criteria;
};
```

This will update the references in your job to match the new jazz.

I would, however, recommend leveraging `ngModel` and `ngChange` in your radios instead. Like:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="controller.category" ng-value="category" ng-change="updateJob(category)" /> {{category.title}}
```

Comment: So, ok, I need a function, there is no way to have it via reference in JS. Fine, thx!